# Lightswitch submit a form on enter key

Tags: c#, .net, lightswitch-2013

I am working on lightswitch application ,in this application normal form submit is happening on button click . I want to do the same on enter key press . I am using Htmlclient.[here check screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGIad.png)

Comment: If you provide a screen-shot of your form (running and in the designer) this will help in organising an answer

Comment: Image screenshot added ,please check

Comment: Based on your screen-shot, I've added a possible approach which should allow the functionality you're looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along similar lines to my answer in the following post:

[Lightswitch HTML - disabling the CTRL + S functionallity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36814261/1301937)

You should be able to achieve this by adding the following code into your screen's created method:

```js
$(window).one("pagechange", function (e, data) {
    var $page = $("#" + screen.details._pageId);
    var $button = $page.find(".msls-save-button,.msls-ok-button");
    $page.keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.which === $.mobile.keyCode.ENTER) {
            $button.trigger("vclick");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

The jQuery mobile pagechange handler is needed to ensure that your screen is rendered (and _pageId is defined) before adding the keydown handler for the <kbd>enter</kbd> key.

If the <kbd>enter</kbd> key is pressed, this handler executes the vclick against the commit button (identified by matching either the msls-save-button or msls-ok-button classes) and this instigates the commit on the screen.